# Rotating the same cube in different directions

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a cube in different directions . But whenever it rotates , a new cube is drawn . But i want the same cube to rotate in different directions . How to do it ?

Here's what im doing now .

```
static GLfloat theta[]={0.0,0.0,0.0};
GLint axis =0;

GLubyte cubeIndices[]={0,3,2,1,
                    2,3,7,6,
                    0,4,7,3,
                    1,2,6,5,
                    4,5,6,7,
                    0,1,5,4};

void displayCallBack()
{


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();


if(ch=='u')
gluLookAt(0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0);//- vertical
else if(ch=='r') 
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);//-right
else if(ch=='l')
gluLookAt(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0);//-left
else if(ch=='d')
gluLookAt(0.0,-1.0,1.0,0.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);//-downward

glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(theta[0],1.0,0.0,0.0);
glRotatef(theta[1],0.0,1.0,0.0);
glRotatef(theta[2],0.0,0.0,1.0);
glColorPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,0,colors);
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,24,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,cubeIndices);
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
}

void myKeyboard(unsigned char key ,int x,int y)
{
switch(key)
{
case 'l': ch='l'; theta[axis]+=90; glutPostRedisplay(); break;
case 'r': ch='r'; theta[axis]+=90; glutPostRedisplay(); break;
case 'u': ch='u'; theta[axis]+=90; glutPostRedisplay(); break;
case 'd': ch='d'; theta[axis]+=90; glutPostRedisplay(); break;
}

}
```

Comment: what's your clear color set to?  If you want help, you'll need to post your entire program.

Comment: I don't think you entirely understood how graphics APIs (in this case OGL) work. Hint: You draw your objects every frame. There is no *new cube*.